# Can't login my webdav built on nginx with right user and password

Tags: nginx, webdav

I build my webdav server this way:

```
apt-get install nginx-full
vim /etc/nginx/conf.d/webdav.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name vps_ip;
    auth_basic              realm_name;
    auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/.credentials.list;
    dav_methods     PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
    dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS;
    dav_access      user:rw group:rw all:r;
    client_max_body_size    0;
    create_full_put_path    on;
}
#add username and  password
echo -n 'userName:' | sudo tee -a /etc/nginx/.credentials.list;
openssl passwd -apr1 | sudo tee -a /etc/nginx/.credentials.list;
#restart my nginx
systemlctl restart nginx
```

Type my vps ip in browser and input username and password, it will pop up the window over and over

[image]

How to fix it then?

1.account and password
I have set account and password as  `sammy`,`sammy`.

```
cat   /etc/nginx/.credentials.list
$apr1$8n9ND3iO$5.vkNPeJZ5h3jJ/d.onJ81
```

2.log

```
cat   /var/log/nginx/access.log
xxxx - - [26/Jul/2021:00:26:12 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 401 597 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
xxxx - - [26/Jul/2021:00:26:13 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 401 597 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
xxxx - - [26/Jul/2021:00:27:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 173 "-" "-"
xxxx - - [26/Jul/2021:00:39:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 195 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CensysInspect/1.1; +https://about.censys.io/)"
cat   /var/log/nginx/error.log
#Nothing in  /var/log/nginx
```

Comment: What is in `/etc/nginx/.credentials.list`?

Comment: And what does the access log and error log have to say?

Comment: Now you can clearly see that the `/etc/nginx/.credentials.list` is not in the correct format.